# Can someone please explain this algorithm in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, scope, subsequence

Quadratic Maximum contiguous subsequence sum algorithm

```
int maxSubSum2( const vector<int> & a)
{
  int maxSum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< a.size(); ++i)
  {
    int thisSum = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < a.size(); ++j)
    {
      thisSum += a[j];
      if (thisSum > maxSum)
        maxSum = thisSum;
    }
  }
  return maxSum;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone can explain how the algorithm works? I am good with for loops, I'm just bad at nested ones. Is "thisSum" always 0 every time the outer for loop on line 8 runs or is it static?

Thank you very much! I am trying really hard to understand the algorithm. Please help me! I really appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: Just so you know, this is a very slow algorithm.  There's _much_ faster algorithms.

Comment: `thisSum` is not static (otherwise it would *actually be declared static*). On every run of the outer loop it's set back to 0.

Answer (score 2):

The outer loop iterates over every element of the vector `a`. On each iteration, `i` will be the index of the current element, it resets `thisSum` to `0`, and it then executes the inner loop.

The inner loop iterates over every element starting from `i`. On each iteration, `j` will be the index of its current element. It then calculates the sum of these elements in `thisSum`.

The outer loop replaces `maxSum` with `thisSum` if it's higher than what it already contains.

So if the vector contains:

```
1 7 -10 2 4
```

the successive iterations of the outer loop will calculate the following values of `thisSum`:

```
1 + 7 + -10 + 2 + 4 = 4
7 + -10 + 2 + 4 = 3
-10 + 2 + 4 = -4
2 + 4 = 6
4 = 4
```

The first iteration it will set `maxSum` to `4`. After the 2nd and 3rd iterations, `thisSum > maxSum` will be false, so it won't change it. On the 4th iteration, `6 > 4`, so it will set `maxSum` to `6`. The last iteration won't change it. Finally, it will return `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the outer for loop loops, this sum is reset to 0 because of the `=0` that is on the first line of the outer loop.

I suggest you modify your function to print i, j, and thisSum in the inner loop so that you can see how they are changing.

Answer (score 0):

Example a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

j starts at the value of i, so it will first start at 0, then 1, then 2 and so on. Thus this second, inner loop is smaller each time the outer loop increments.

thisSum is reset to 0 each time as it is NOT static. If it was, it would be labeled static.

Basically, in this algorithm the outer loop is used to push the 'starting index' forward, with the inner loop used to actually add all the elements of the array / vector together.

So the executions of the inner loop for the example above would be like this:

```
Execution 1: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
Execution 2: 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
Execution 3: 3 + 4 + 5
Execution 4: 4 + 5
Execution 5: 5
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

thisSum at your code line 8 is reset at beginning part of loop *i*,

but thisSum in your loop j is keep adding the array *a[ ]* element in loop *j*.

---

Normally I will substitute value and assume value to understand how the loop work.

Let assume vector a has 3 int elements 10,-20,100

therefore a.size() = 3

```
//maxSum is initialized in the function
int maxSum = 0;

//Start First i loop
int i = 0; i < 3; 
int thisSum = 0; 

int j = i = 0; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[0];
//thisSum = 10
//10 > 0
if (thisSum > maxSum) maxSum = thisSum = 10;
int j = i = 1; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[1];
//thisSum = -10
// -10 not > 10
int j = i = 2; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[2];
//thisSum = 90
//90 > 10
if (thisSum > maxSum) maxSum = thisSum = 90;
//End First i loop

//Start 2nd i loop
int i = 1; i < 3; 
int thisSum = 0; 

int j = i = 1; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[1];
//thisSum = -20
//-20 not > 90
int j = i = 2; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[2];
//thisSum = 80
//80 not > 90
//End 2nd i loop

//Start 3rd i loop
int i = 2; i < 3; 
int thisSum = 0; 

int j = i = 2; j < 3; 
thisSum += a[2];
//thisSum = 100
//100 > 90
if (thisSum > maxSum) maxSum = thisSum = 100;
//End 3rd i loop

//return 100
//return maxSum
```

The concept of the function is it try to get the maximum sum by step by step remove the item from smallest index element to the largest index argument.

1st loop i : maxSum = 90

2nd loop i : maxSum = 90 (remove 10)

3rd loop i : maxSum = 100 (remove 10,-20)